# Blog system with code interpreting

Tags: blogs

I wanna create blog site where i'll publishing something..
I looking for blog which can recognize code section where can i paste code like here and it will be interpreted like source code for example ....Can someone write me some Blog system with this feature?
I am sorry. bad english.
Thanks.

Comment: What Blog back end are you using? Wordpress, Drupal, Magento, .... there are plugins available to extend the features of any blog to do this....

Comment: very highly unlikely that anyone here is going to write it for you without getting paid.  However, there are already lots of tools out there that does code coloring for you... http://code.google.com/p/qlcolorcode/ for example. On my blog I use Telerik RadEditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of blogs that support code snippets, but it really amounts to personal preference.  The best engines I have seen support extensions, and then you can install the extension of your favorite code snippet display.  I prefer [SyntaxHighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) installed on [BlogEngine.Net](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/), but there are really lots of good solutions out there.

Comment: Aaa thanks BlogEngine will be fine ...what i know it isn't require Sql db ... true? 

thanks to all it is what i looked for

Comment: Can u write me how to install SyntaxHighlighter to BlogEngine?

Comment: You can find the BlogEngine.Net extension for SyntaxHighlighter here: http://sh2forbe.codeplex.com/ .  Once you have downloaded it, you can install it as a extension to your blog using the admin panel on the extensions tab.  You will also want to decide what tool you are going to use to write your blog posts, so it can be SyntaxHighlighter enabled also.  I prefer Windows Live Writer so here is a link that explains a little bit about that : http://precode.codeplex.com/ .